# XLookupString returning a UTF-8 code (Latin-1 to UTF-8)

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I'm trying to use the function `XLookupString`.
According to the [documentation](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XLookupString.html), it is supposed to return a Latin-1 code. How could I convert it or what should I use instead this function so I get a UTF-8 code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get UTF-8 input with X11 Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246848/get-utf-8-input-with-x11-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read chapter 11 of the Xlib programming manual: [google books link](http://books.google.com/books?id=d8tByjvMmIwC&dq=Xlib+programming+manual&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=iF30SvDTDYrEMJXniekF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).  You are looking for `XmbLookupString()` or `XwcLookupString()` but they are not drop-in substitutes for `XLookupString()`.  I am not an expert in this but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Direct manpage links might be easier: http://www.xfree86.org/current/XmbLookupString.3.html http://www.xfree86.org/current/XwcLookupString.3.html

Comment: The Google book is only a preview, but there is a [complete online version of the book](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_PG/sgi_html/ch11.html) — apparently there have been only "minor revisions" between both, Google's version being 3 years older or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Xutf8* family of functions that can be used for this, specifically, there exists a `Xutf8LookupString()`. [X*LookupString man page](http://www.xfree86.org/current/Xutf8LookupString.3.html)