# xlookupstring return non-printable character in CTRl+'letters'

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, x11, keyboard-events, xlib

I've made a program that allows me to read keyboard character but when I tested  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ 'letters', I recognized  my input is unknown character. Why can't I capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 'letters'(character)?

This is my sample code:

```
 XLookupString(KeyEvent,&cChar,1,&keysym,NULL);
cout<<"key is: "<<keysym<<"  char "<<cChar<<"  ev_type "<<ev.type<<endl;
```

and here is my terminal output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you can print control characters?

Comment: is there any way to avoid print control character ,i cannot detect their code because they are the same character cod , in other words i mean code for "a" is 97 and for "CTRL + a " is the same 97

Comment: XLookupString returns a *string*. Use it. Don't use keycodes or keysyms.

Comment: i use it as cChar in my code but as you can see i detect an undefined character i want to detect defined character

Comment: There is no such thing as undefined character.  If XLookupString returns you something, be rest assured it is defined. You may have detected a non-printable character, which is absolutely normal. If you only want printable characters, use `isprint`. Also bear in mind that XLookupString returns a *string*, i.e. there sometimes may be more than one character, or zero characters.

Comment: Read again, use `isprint`.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @n.m. my problem solved

Comment: dear @n.m I have another issue ,when i change my keyboard language to Russian isprint accept Russian character as none printable character is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: This is way more complicated than it ought to be. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246848/get-utf-8-input-with-x11-display Briefy, you want to set up an X input metod and use Xutf8LookupString.