# How do I handle non US keyboard layouts with Xlib and xkb?

Tags: c, input, xlib

I'm using a Swedish keyboard layout and can't get access to many keys such as the bracket keys since I have to press AltGr to get access to them. I'm using the `XkbKeycodeToKeysym` to translate keycodes to keysyms but I only get 0 as a keysym when pressing AltGr.

AltGr is Mod5Mask according to the X.h file. The state is 128 when pressing it.

I've tried to pass different levels and groups to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym` with no results.

Comment: Keysyms are symbols engraved on (virtual) keys, not characters or strings you generate by pressing said keys. If you need to read what the user types, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246848/get-utf-8-input-with-x11-display/18288346#18288346).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I needed was `Xutf8LookupString` and using that.
I followed this [tutorial](https://handmade.network/forums/articles/t/2834-tutorial_a_tour_through_xlib_and_related_technologies) for when configuring the input context.