# UTF-8 input and using XGetICValues

Tags: linux, utf-8, x11, xlib

I have found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246848/get-utf-8-input-with-x11-display) (accepted answer) of UTF-8 input but I wonder if that example is correct. The result of `XGetICValues` may be passed to `XSelectInput`:

```
unsigned long mask = 0;

if (!XGetICValues(ic, XNFilterEvents, &mask, NULL)) 
{
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, other_masks | mask);
}
```

Could you please explain what are implications of the above code ? Is it mandatory to get a correct UTF-8 input ? Should I also call `XFilterEvent` after executing the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I also call XFilterEvent after executing the above code ?

I suspect you should: for correct UTF-8 input handling, it's not only about getting the event mask and selecting the input events, but also potentially filtering these events to properly handle multibyte or special input sequences.

The [`XFilterEvent`](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XFilterEvent.3.xhtml) should be utilized within the event loop. It will help in managing the input method to interpret multibyte or special key sequences correctly.
As mentioned in "[XLIB Programming Manual / Filtering Events](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xlib-programming-manual/9780596806187/ch11s09.html)", it is called right after [`XNextEvent()`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XNextEvent.3.xhtml).

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>
#include <X11/Xlocale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Your initialization code
    
    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        if (XFilterEvent(&ev, win))  // Filter the event through the input method
            continue;
        switch(ev.type){
        case MappingNotify:
            XRefreshKeyboardMapping(&ev.xmapping);
            break;
        case KeyPress:
            {
                int count = 0;
                KeySym keysym = 0;
                char buf[20];
                Status status = 0;
                count = Xutf8LookupString(ic, (XKeyPressedEvent*)&ev, buf, 20, &keysym, &status);
    
                printf("count: %d\n", count);
                if (status == XBufferOverflow)
                    printf("BufferOverflow\n");
    
                if (count)
                    printf("buffer: %.*s\n", count, buf);
 
                if (status == XLookupKeySym || status == XLookupBoth) {
                    printf("status: %d\n", status);
                }
                printf("pressed KEY: %d\n", (int)keysym);
            }
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            // Rest of your code for other cases
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

If `XFilterEvent` returns `True`, indicating that the event has been filtered and handled by the input method, the `continue` statement is executed to skip the rest of the loop and process the next event.

```bash
+--------------------+    XNFilterEvents        +--------------+
| Input Context (IC) |------------------------->| Event Mask   |
+--------------------+                          +--------------+
           |                                           |
      XGetICValues                               Retrieved Mask
           |                                           |
           V                                           V
+--------------------+    other_masks | mask    +--------------+
| XSelectInput       |------------------------->| Event Input  |
+--------------------+                          +--------------+
           |                                           |
           |                                    +--------------+
           |                                    | X Event      |
           |                                    +--------------+
           |                                           |
           V                                           V
+--------------------+    XFilterEvent          +--------------+
| Event Loop         |------------------------->| Event Filter |
+--------------------+    (optional)            +--------------+
```

- The [Input Context (IC)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3916/xtxlib-7/index.html#xtxlib-9) is queried to get the event mask which is needed for `XSelectInput` to know which events to listen for.
- [`XSelectInput`](http://www.delafond.org/traducmanfr/X11/man3/XSelectInput.3x.html) is called with a combination of other masks and the retrieved mask to specify the events that should be reported for the specified window.
- In the event loop, `XFilterEvent` is called to filter the event queue for the relevant input events, particularly useful when dealing with multibyte or special input sequences. This step is marked as optional, since it's based on the requirement to handle special input sequences.

Comment: So passing a mask retrieved from XGetICValues to XSelectInput is obligatory to correctly filter events, right ?

Comment: @Irbis Passing the event mask retrieved from XGetICValues to XSelectInput is not obligatory, but it can be crucial for correctly filtering and handling input events, especially in cases where there are multi-byte or special input sequences. The mask obtained from XGetICValues using the XNFilterEvents attribute provides the set of events that the Input Method requires to operate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was my example/answer I feel obliged to chime in.

In my example and with my particular IM, you don't need to call `XGetICValues`. It sets the mask to just `KeyPressMask|KeyReleaseMask` which I set anyway. However in general, for other choices of input mask and/or for other input methods, you do need to call `XGetICValues`.

Obviously, if you are not setting either `KeyPressMask` or `KeyReleaseMask` yourself, it won't work. But there's more than that. If the input method involves an on-screen keyboard, the IM will need to process mouse events, which won't be delivered if you don't use the mask from `XGetICValues`.

So in general, yes, do call `XSelectInput` and pass the mask to `XSelectInput`. And yes you do need to call `XFilterEvent` because that's where the IM magic happens.

I will update my answer you reference to reflect this.